# How does the IN operator works in NEO4J when the first operator is a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using something like this in a NEO4J query

`return [1] in [3,25,6,2,4,1]`

and returns true.

However when I execute something like

`return [1,2] in [3,25,6,2,4,1]`

it returns false.

So the question is how is specified to work the IN operator on Lists. I couldn't find any specification on this, and I am not sure if it is consistent among all versions.

Comment: In version 3.0.3, this `return [1] in [3,25,6,2,4,1]` return `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this ever did work, I'm pretty sure it's a bug (though I'm still hunting for the github issue). The behavior you're looking for should be achieved using `ALL`.

```
RETURN ALL(x IN [1, 2] WHERE x IN [3, 25, 6, 2, 4, 1])
```

Collections (`neo4j` lists) are not sets, they can have duplicate entries, so `IN` should be expected to perform membership checking, not intersection. Set operations are currently relegated to `apoc` or other external procedures.

If your first operand *is* a list, though, it will check to see if that whole list matches any single item in the second operand. So, for example, `[1, 2] IN [[1, 2], [3, 4]]` will return `true`, but `[1, 2] IN [1, 2, 3, 4]` will return `false.